# How to check the border-width of "before" pseudoclass

Tags: jquery

Here I have some html

```
<label for="timeline-does-not-filter-content-based-one-of-the-following-properties1">::before
"Workflows"</label>
```

the pseudoclass :before has sometimes applied style

```
border-width: 4px;
```

How can I check with jquery that it has border width equal to 4px applied. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin#5734583), css `:after` and `:before` rules aren't part of the DOM, and therefore can't be altered (or in your case checked) using jQuery's DOM methods.

What you can do is applied the `border-width: 4px` style based on the `label` class and check if your `label` has this class with `.hasClass('myClass')`.

Like:

```
label.bordered:before {
  border-width: 4px;
}
```

And check it:

```
$('label').hasClass('bordered')
```